# Unity/Oculus SDK on Mac High sierra?

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Ok Ive read https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/60606/do-not-update-to-mac-os-high-sierra that talks about Oculus SDK for Unity 1.24 and up not working for Mac. I went back to 1.22 however, and following the VRTK tutorial installed Oculus SDK 1.22.

I dont have any errors that prevent running but the plugin isn't working - I get this

[image]

What are my options here? Is there any way to develop for Oculus Rift in Unity on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

Oculus isn't supporting platform other than Windows with certain releases. But, if you take a look at [Oculus Developer's Forum post - "Error when loading in Oculus Utilities for Unity"](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/66847/error-when-loading-in-oculus-utilities-for-unity), it mentions that you can get OVRPlugin.cs to compile on Mac (or Linux) if you wrap some of the error ares with a `#if !OVRPLUGIN_UNSUPPORTED_PLATFORM`, `#else`, and make it `return` or `return false;` and then end it off with an `#endif` to make it work.

There is also a link to a file that you can try to download, but I was able to put the preprocessor directives in the right areas to get it to compile.